# Mysql Select with IFNULL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use IFNULL to determine to use a column in a where clause, but I dont believe I am doing it correctly.  Does anybody have any suggestions?

```
SELECT * FROM bdesclookuptable 
WHERE LOWER('Santa Clause Home Address') LIKE CONCAT('%',LOWER(lText),'%') 
AND  LOWER('Santa Clause Home Address') LIKE CONCAT('%',LOWER(IFNULL(plusand,'ilikethispaintingoverhead')),'%') 
AND  LOWER('Santa Clause Home Address') NOT LIKE CONCAT('%',LOWER(IFNULL(andnot,'ilikethispaintingoverhead')),'%');

table 
id  lText          bbid ttype   andnot     plusand
16  Home Address    11  13      null        Santa
17  Home Address    11  13      Work        Santa
18  Home Address    12  15     Mrs Clause   null
```

I want this query to pull only the record with an id of 16.

Comment: add `and id=16` ? Explain what you want extract from your database plz

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant I would think that it is not about exactly the 16, but about the combinations of properties. Everything else would be pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 conditions. They all must be fulfilled in order to succeed.

Condition 1 is met with all three records, as `Home Address` is contained in `Santa Clause Home Address`.

Condition 2 is met with 16 and 17. 18 fails as `plusand` is replaced with the long word not contained in the pattern.

Condition 3 is met with all three again.

So you should get 16 and 17.

In order to avoid the 17, you should make one of the conditions fail at it, e. g. with an `andnot` value contained in the string in order to make it fail.